# Recursion not working for higher terms

Tags: recursion

I am trying to find the terms x9,x10,x11 and y6,y7,y8 and so on from the recursive relation given in the code.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
defs = <|x[0] -> 0, x[1] -> 0, x[2] -> \[Alpha]/2, x[3] -> 1/6, 
   x[4] -> (k^2*\[Alpha])/12, x[5] -> (1/120)*(2*k^2 + k*R*\[Gamma]), 
   x[6] -> 1/720 (3*k^4*\[Alpha] - 2*k*R*\[Epsilon]*\[Gamma]), 
   x[7] -> 1/1680 (-k*R*\[Epsilon]*\[Gamma] + k^3*R*\[Gamma] + k^4), 
   x[8] -> -1/40320 (8*k^3*R*\[Epsilon]*\[Gamma] - 4*k^6*\[Alpha] + k^2*R*\[Gamma] + 4*k*R*\[Epsilon]*\[Gamma]), y[-5] -> 0, y[-4] -> 0, y[-3] -> 0, y[-2] -> 0, y[-1] -> 0, y[0] -> 0, 
   y[1] -> \[Gamma], y[2] -> 0, y[3] -> (k^2*\[Gamma])/6, 
   y[4] -> -(k*\[Alpha])/24, y[5] -> 1/120 (\[Gamma]*k^4 - k)|>;

eqns = {(n + 1)*(n + 2)*(n + 3)*(n + 4)*x[n + 4] - 
     2*k^2*(n + 1)*(n + 2)*x[n + 2] + k^4*x[n] - k*R*y[n] + 
     k*R*\[Epsilon]*y[n - 1] + k*R*\[Epsilon]*y[n - 2]*1/2 + 
     k*R*\[Epsilon]*y[n - 3]*1/6 + k*R*\[Epsilon]*y[n - 4]*1/24 + 
     k*R*\[Epsilon]*y[n - 5]*1/120 == 
    0, (n + 1)*(n + 2)*y[n + 2] - k^2*y[n] + k*x[n] == 0};

Do[AppendTo[defs, #] & /@ First[Solve[eqns /. {n -> i} /. defs]], {i, 2, 10}] // FullSimplify
defs
```

I am not getting the next few terms and I'm unable to figure out the reason. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are you solving for? Also, have a look at some of your inputs, Is this what you expect? `In[4]:= eqns /. {n -> 2} /. defs

Out[4]= {-((3 k^4 \[Alpha])/2) + k R \[Gamma] \[Epsilon] + 
   1/2 (3 k^4 \[Alpha] - k R \[Gamma] \[Epsilon]) == 0, True}`

Comment: I am solving for x and y for different values of n. I have edited my inputs `x6 and x8`. These inputs I obtained by solving the recursive relation by-hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define an explicit recursion with [memoization](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/WriteAFunctionThatRemembersComputedValues.html):

```
Clear[x, y];

x[0] = 0;
x[1] = 0;
x[2] = α/2;
x[3] = 1/6;
x[4] = k^2*α/12;
x[5] = (2*k^2 + k*R*γ)/120;
x[6] = (3*k^4*α - k*R*ε*γ)/720;
x[7] = (-k*R*ε*γ + k^3*R*γ + k^4)/1680;
x[8] = -(6*k^3*R*ε*γ - 4*k^6*α + k^2*R*γ + 4*k*R*ε*γ)/40320;

x[n_] := x[n] =
    -((k (120 k^3 x[n-4] - 240 k (n-3) (n-2) x[n-2] +
    R ε (y[n-9] + 5 (y[n-8] + 4 (y[n-7] + 3 y[n-6] + 6 y[n-5]))) -
    120 R y[n-4]))/(120 (n-3) (n-2) (n-1) n)) // Expand

y[-5] = 0;
y[-4] = 0;
y[-3] = 0;
y[-2] = 0;
y[-1] = 0;
y[0] = 0;
y[1] = γ;
y[2] = 0;
y[3] = k^2*γ/6;
y[4] = -k*α/24;
y[5] = (γ*k^4 - k)/120;

y[n_] := y[n] = (k (-x[n-2] + k y[n-2]))/((n-1) n) // Expand
```

Now you can request any value:

```
x[20]
(*    (k^18 α)/243290200817664000 - (29 k^14 R α)/347557429739520000 + (k^10 R^2 α)/28622376566784000 - (k^14 R γ)/347557429739520000 + (k^10 R^2 γ)/69511485947904000 - (k^6 R^3 γ)/2432902008176640000 + (79 k^8 R ε)/2534272925184000 + (89 k^10 R ε)/10137091700736000 + (k^12 R ε)/1609062174720000 - (k^4 R^2 ε)/526602166272000 - (197 k^6 R^2 ε)/101370917007360000 - (k^8 R^2 ε)/3003582726144000 + (197 k^10 R α ε)/8109673360588800 + (k^12 R α ε)/275839229952000 - (23 k^6 R^2 α ε)/8688935743488000 - (1087 k^8 R^2 α ε)/810967336058880000 - (503 k^11 R γ ε)/101370917007360000 - (k^13 R γ ε)/851856445440000 - (29 k^15 R γ ε)/304112751022080000 - (41 k^6 R^2 γ ε)/13367593451520000 + (43 k^7 R^2 γ ε)/1668657070080000 - (61 k^8 R^2 γ ε)/101370917007360000 + (k^9 R^2 γ ε)/108418093056000 + (29 k^11 R^2 γ ε)/34755742973952000 - (k^5 R^3 γ ε)/3556874280960000 - (29 k^7 R^3 γ ε)/304112751022080000 + (k^4 R^2 ε^2)/77441495040000 + (197 k^6 R^2 ε^2)/50685458503680000 + (257 k^4 R^2 α ε^2)/7899032494080000 + (8117 k^6 R^2 α ε^2)/405483668029440000 + (59 k^8 R^2 α ε^2)/40548366802944000 - (k^3 R^2 γ ε^2)/74264408064000 - (12679 k^5 R^2 γ ε^2)/152056375511040000 - (1763 k^7 R^2 γ ε^2)/30035827261440000 - (3149 k^9 R^2 γ ε^2)/405483668029440000 + (593 k^5 R^3 γ ε^2)/810967336058880000 - (k^5 R^3 γ ε^3)/16895152834560000    *)

y[20]
(*    -((k^17 α)/54064489070592000) + (k^13 R α)/10532043325440000 - (k^9 R^2 α)/101370917007360000 + (k^13 R γ)/115852476579840000 - (k^9 R^2 γ)/115852476579840000 - (1721 k^7 R ε)/202741834014720000 - (43 k^9 R ε)/10137091700736000 - (k^11 R ε)/1930874609664000 + (k^5 R^2 ε)/5792623828992000 + (k^7 R^2 ε)/13516122267648000 - (k^9 R α ε)/103970171289600 - (67 k^11 R α ε)/27032244535296000 + (k^5 R^2 α ε)/34755742973952000 + (149 k^7 R^2 α ε)/810967336058880000 + (109 k^10 R γ ε)/40548366802944000 + (k^12 R γ ε)/905097473280000 + (k^14 R γ ε)/6206382673920000 + (k^5 R^2 γ ε)/2430471536640000 - (97 k^6 R^2 γ ε)/22526870446080000 + (157 k^7 R^2 γ ε)/810967336058880000 - (11 k^8 R^2 γ ε)/3686215163904000 - (k^10 R^2 γ ε)/2126662594560000 + (23 k^6 R^3 γ ε)/2432902008176640000 - (k^5 R^2 ε^2)/2896311914496000 - (k^5 R^2 α ε^2)/662014151884800 - (k^7 R^2 α ε^2)/3556874280960000 + (k^4 R^2 γ ε^2)/196582256640000 + (1831 k^6 R^2 γ ε^2)/202741834014720000 + (k^8 R^2 γ ε^2)/429083246592000    *)
```

or make a list of values for further use:

```
Table[x[n], {n, 0, 20}]
(*    ... lots of output ...    *)
```

Comment: Nice answer (+1). I think starting conditions `x[0],...x[4],y[-5],...y[1]` would be sufficient! Why `RSolve`won't solve it ?

Comment: What I have seen it that `RSolve` takes forever to even compute 10 terms. @Ulrich Neumann

Comment: Out of all the methods that I've tried so far, I must say that this is the most efficient one. The way you've defined `x[n]` and `y[n]` makes the difference. I have spent hours just calculating the `x` and `y` terms for different recursive relations. This is very helpful, thanks a lot!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I think the starting conditions need a bit of work anyway, because some of them seem to be attempts to solve the recursion "manually" but making mistakes.